# Why the quick sort is inefficient when there are many duplicate element?

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

When I sort some data that have many duplicate element,the quick sort algorithm is inefficient.Can anyone explain why?
Here is my quick sort code:

```
int partition(int arr[],int low,int high)
{
    int i = low + 1;
    int j = high;
    int tmp = arr[low];
    while(1)
    {
        while(j != low && arr[j] > tmp) --j;   //from right to left
        while(i != high && arr[i] <= tmp) ++i;  //from left to right
        if(i < j)
        {
            int t = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = t;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return j;
}

void QuickSort(int arr[],int low,int high)
{
    if(low < high)
    {
        int j = partition(arr,low,high);
        int t = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[low];
        arr[low] = t;
        if(low < j)
            QuickSort(arr,low,j-1);
        if(high > j)
            QuickSort(arr,j+1,high);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an answer that includes a version of quicksort that is efficient at handling duplicates and already sorted or reverse sorted files.

Comment: @rcgldr - Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that not only does your input have many duplicates, but the duplicate elements *are consecutive*, which makes the input mostly sorted to start with. A mostly sorted container is quick sort's worst case, with performance degrading to as poorly as `O(n^2)`.

For mostly ordered input other sorts like heap sort and merge sort will offer better performance since their worst case is simply a higher constant on their average case.

Comment: Duplicates, mostly sorted (or mostly reverse sorted) isn't an issue for the implementation of quicksort in my answer. In fact, it takes less time if the data has duplicates or is mostly sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The example quicksort code below is similar to the example code in the question, but it takes less time if there are more duplicates, and is fastest if the data is already sorted or reverse sorted. The main difference is the usage of a modified Hoare partition scheme (dynamic pivot) and a median of 3 to choose the initial pivot. There should still be patterns that cause worst case performance, but I'm not sure what those patterns would be.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

```
void QuickSort(uint32_t a[], int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo, j = (lo + hi)/2, k = hi;
    uint32_t pivot;
    if (a[k] < a[i])            // median of 3
        std::swap(a[k], a[i]);
    if (a[j] < a[i])
        std::swap(a[j], a[i]);
    if (a[k] < a[j])
        std::swap(a[k], a[j]);
    pivot = a[j];
    while (i <= k) {            // partition
        while (a[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (a[k] > pivot)
            k--;
        if (i <= k) {
            std::swap(a[i], a[k]);
            i++;
            k--;
        }
    }
    if (lo < k)                 // recurse
        QuickSort(a, lo, k);
    if (i < hi)
        QuickSort(a, i, hi);
}
```